# Getting "404" while running my springboot app on docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I have created a spring boot hello world application and it is running on my local machine "localhost:8080/hello". I wanted to run my application using docker so I created a docker file which looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-jre17-temurin-focal 
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps 
COPY. .
EXPOSE 8080 
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

After running the command in the terminal "docker build -t firstcode .", it creates a docker image and when I run the image on my machine it shows "404 Not Found". What should I do to run my spring-boot docker image, which steps I am missing?

I tried to change the docker base image but it was not successful.

Comment: can you provide your docker run command ?

Comment: I am not running any command, I just go to the docker engine and click on run the image and it automatically runs the image on a localhost 8080.

Comment: seems that you don't packakge with mvn, not sure is it helpfule https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198251/docker-with-maven-and-tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encountering a "404" error while running a Spring Boot application in Docker, there are several potential causes to investigate:

- Check Application Startup Logs - First, check the logs of your Spring Boot application to ensure that it starts up successfully without any errors.
- Verify Docker Container Status.
- Check Container Ports Mapping - If your Spring Boot application
  exposes a web service, ensure that you have correctly mapped the
  container's port to a port on the host machine in your Docker
  configuration.
- Inspect Docker Container Logs
- Ensure the Application is Deployed Correctly
- Check Network Configuration - Check firewall settings and network
  configurations if necessary. Inspect Dockerfile and Docker Compose
  Configuration

By investigating these potential causes, you should be able to identify and resolve the "404" error when running your Spring Boot application in Docker.